# Cocoa iOS Make CGPoints "Bigger" in UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, subclass, cgpoint

Is it possible to make the default `CGPoint` size for an iOS app "bigger"?

*For example*, the iPhone's main view is 320 points wide - is it possible to change that to, say, 100 points, and base all calculations on that 100 (as in still be able to use `CGRectMake`, get sizes etc. normally).

So does anyone know how to subclass `UIView` in such a way as to make the above work, and, more importantly, would Apple allow it?

Thanks for  your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(320/100, 320/100)` transform to your view so that it is scaled, and 100 points will be scaled to `100 * (320/100) = 320` points wide.

*Or course, don't use magic numbers like above, but use some constant for the value `100` and something like `[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width` (or `view.window.screen.applicationFrame.size.width` or anything similar) to get the width of the screen instead of the value `320` (because magic numbers are bad, and we never know if the size of the screen will change in any future like the height just changed with iPhone5)*

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `UIView`s `transform` property. But this is probably a bad idea: If you rescale your coordinate system, almost all your views are going to be misaligned with the screen's pixels. This will lead to blurry display of text, lines and other graphics.

Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: I want to do this because it'd take less processing power to check simple collisions, for example if I had a 3*3 view in a 'normal' 320*480 view, I would have to check 9 points, but with the scaled view I can just check one...

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization (and a pretty bad collision detection algorithm) to me. Maybe have a look at Box2D or the like.